# dot notation for horizontal flow

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a graph which is shallow than deep.
I wanted it to flow horizontally instead of vertically as is the default.

E.g. 
instead of

```
    a 
  /   \
b       c
```

I want

```
    b
  /
a
  \
    c
```

Can we do this in DOT notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  At the top of your graph add:

```
digraph example {
  rankdir=LR;
  a -> b
  a -> c
}
```

This will orient the graph from left to right.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

References:

[Dot User Guide](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/dotguide.pdf)